# Store human readable layer name in QGIS style files?

Tags: qgis, layers, style, layer-name

QGIS 2 and 3 as well seem not to store the Layer name (set via Layer Properties | Source | Settings | Layer name or via 'Rename' in the layers context menu) in styles files. I.e. if i have a PostGIS table *'flst_teil'* and would like to have it in the Layers Panel in a nice human-readable form like *'Flurstück Teil'*.

For QGIS 3 that astounds me even more, since herein I can explicitly select which configuration tab of a layer I wish to store:

[image]

Is this intented behaviour or a bug? Do I have a chance to achieve this or do I have to rename the layers *any time* I load them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Layer name" is not stored in the QML file.

It will be stored in a saved project, but not in a style file.

I would recommend submitting a bug report/feature request:

https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/issues

I think in the past (when you could not choose what parts of the style to save) this would not have been a good improvement. Since you would often copy styles from one layer to a completely different one. But saving the layer name in the "Layer Configuration" does make sense. At least when it has been specifically modified.

Comment: I strongly disagree on that "I would often copy styles from one layer to another", since a broad variety of layer characteristics (e.g. using categorized or even rule-based renderers, field and form definietion, metadata, ...) depend to such extent on the attribute structure of the table that it is virtually impossible to reuse a complex style for different tables. cp https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20863

Comment: The behavior could also be different between saving a style file and copying a style. But my use case for copying styles would very often be between different layers.